# How can i bind datagrid to some properties of a class in wpf?

Tags: wpf, class, data-binding, datagrid

Is it possible to bind a datagrid to only **selective** members of a class?
The way I have made the binding presently, all the class variables have been binded(one to one mapped) to datagrid's columns.

```
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }
    }
```

Now i want only a few class properties(not all) to be binded to the datagrid.

Comment: Yes it is possible but... Show us some code! Your class, your DataGrid, and your objective: what exactly do you want to bind?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, Just turn off the AutoGenerateColumns and manually specify them

In MainWindow.xaml

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Hello}" Header="Hello" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding World}" Header="World" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

In MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
  public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new[] { new FakeViewModel() };
    }
}
```

In FakeViewModel.cs

```
namespace WpfApplication4
{
  class FakeViewModel
  {
    public FakeViewModel()
    {
        Hello = "Hello";
        World = "World";
        Then = DateTime.Now;
    }
    public DateTime Then { get; set; }
    public string Hello { get; set; }
    public string World { get; set; }
  }
}
```

Please note the unused Property Then!

Comment: I have extended the example so you can see more clearly that it does use a class. However, are you suggesting that you still want to auto generate the columns and simply exclude some of them?

Comment: thanks! that was pretty much what i was looking for. however if there's a way to do it without setting auto generate columns, i'd really like to know.